# How can I create keyboard shortcuts where I can tap a modifier key twice to perform a function?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, I'd like to be able to press `Alt` twice to open a terminal window.

Comment: It depends on your DE/WM

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Your question is too generalised. Please add information like what OS and Desktop Environment you are using.